# In what scenarios we need to use jQuery in mvc?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

Being a beginner to MVC, still I am unable to understand in what scenarios we need to use jQuery, the relation between jQuery and MVC.
So far I noticed that we use jQuery a lot in MVC and without having knowledge in jQuery it’s not possible to learn MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is understand the difference between the **server** and the **client**.

[ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) lives on the server. MVC is a framework for serving up web requests. You can write MVC applications that use 0 lines of JavaScript or jQuery.

The client-side JavaScript, specifically [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), is its own monster. jQuery provides shortcuts for working and manipulating the DOM. jQuery and JavaScript is independent of the server, and can be used with any type of web server, Microsoft stack or otherwise.

The two are very closely related because there is a lot of functionality where constant communication between the server and the client, or pages that change as the user performs various actions, is almost necessary functionality in "modern" web applications.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery in MVC framework from the version 3 is used for

- client side unobtrusive validation
- unobtrusive Ajax

It provides an elegant CSS 3–based syntax for traversing your DOM, a fluent API for
manipulating and animating DOM elements, and extremely concise wrappers for Ajax calls—all
carefully abstracted to eliminate cross-browser differences.